# how to create an hta document whith batch file

Tags: html, batch-file

I want to send my friend an hta file to help my friend learn to code. but I also thought what if I make a batch file that downloads the hta document onto his computer. (ps the code had some personal info so I used a sample from my  website)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/icon">
</head>

<title>welcome - gabriel.karimov.com</title>
<body style = 'background-color: black'>
stuff I post on this website.</h1>
</br>
</br>
<center>
<h1>Hello, my name is [data expunged] I hope you love all the stuff I post on this website.</h1>
</br>
</br>
<center><img src = "./images/minecraft.png" width="50%" height="50%"></br>
<a href="goaway.html" style="font-size:60px">cool stuff</a></br>
<a href="game.html" style="font-size:60px">game</a></br>
<a href="cast.html" style="font-size:60px">credits</a></br>
<a href="Gabriel.html" style="font-size:60px">DO NOT LOOK HERE!</a></br>
<a href="job.html" style="font-size:60px">jobs</a></br>
<a href="yo.html" style="font-size:60px">code for this website</a></br>
<a href="my.html" style="font-size:60px">youtuber test</a></br>
<a href="https://web.roblox.com/catalog/?Category=1&CreatorName=chiefanemone11 "target="_blank" style="font-size:60px">roblox creations</a></br>
<a href="about:blank#blocked "target="_blank" style="font-size:60px">roblox creations</a></br>
<form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend style = 'color: orange'>Text input</legend>
        <p>
          <label>Text box</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "mytext"
                 value = "have fun with text" />
        </p>
</center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Before you consider helping someone else to create their own HTA files, I'd advise that you make improvements to your own. The formatting/indentation of what you've submitted here is awful, it creates nothing but confusion. As for your question, I've never heard of anything so ridiculous. Why would you not provide the plain text content in one or more files, (even the batch file itself), or send them a direct link to a tutorial on your own website? The only reason I can think of for the type of behavior you're suggesting is the opposite of helping somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save this as a .bat file:

```
<!-- :
    @echo off
    mshta.exe "%~f0"
    exit /b %errorlevel%
-->


<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/icon">
</head>

<title>welcome - gabriel.karimov.com</title>
<body style = 'background-color: black'>
stuff I post on this website.</h1>
</br>
</br>
<center>
<h1>Hello, my name is [data expunged] I hope you love all the stuff I post on this website.</h1>
</br>
</br>
<center><img src = "./images/minecraft.png" width="50%" height="50%"></br>
<a href="goaway.html" style="font-size:60px">cool stuff</a></br>
<a href="game.html" style="font-size:60px">game</a></br>
<a href="cast.html" style="font-size:60px">credits</a></br>
<a href="Gabriel.html" style="font-size:60px">DO NOT LOOK HERE!</a></br>
<a href="job.html" style="font-size:60px">jobs</a></br>
<a href="yo.html" style="font-size:60px">code for this website</a></br>
<a href="my.html" style="font-size:60px">youtuber test</a></br>
<a href="https://web.roblox.com/catalog/?Category=1&CreatorName=chiefanemone11 "target="_blank" style="font-size:60px">roblox creations</a></br>
<a href="about:blank#blocked "target="_blank" style="font-size:60px">roblox creations</a></br>
<form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend style = 'color: orange'>Text input</legend>
        <p>
          <label>Text box</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "mytext"
                 value = "have fun with text" />
        </p>
</center>

</body>

</html>
```